# Combine 4 SELECT queries on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Im trying to combine these 3 mysql statements. I've been using the UNION and JOIN Keyword however it doesnt come up with the output I desired. Any suggestions? This is my 3 statements.

```
SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Abstract Reasoning'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10

SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='English'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30

SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Mathematics'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30

SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Science'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30
```

I tried combining the first 2 statements like so:

```
SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Abstract Reasoning'
LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='English'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30;
```

however it only reads the second LIMIT query wherein t outputs 30 rows only.

I would like to create a query where in a total of 100 rows is displayed and randomized according to index. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html),

To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:

```
(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Abstract Reasoning'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10)

UNION

(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='English'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30)

UNION

(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Mathematics'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30)

UNION

(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE Subject='Science'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30 )
```

Comment: lol. that worked. i forgot about the parenthesis when working with multiple queries. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parentheses in the query when using UNION and LIMIT, like:

```
(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion WHERE Subject='Abstract Reasoning' LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM entrancequestion WHERE Subject='English' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 SELECT TOP 10 * FROM entrancequestion
 WHERE Subject='Abstract Reasoning'
 UNION
 SELECT TOP 30 * FROM entrancequestion
 WHERE Subject='English'
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care so much about the first one having `LIMIT 10`:

```
SELECT * FROM entrancequestion
WHERE
    Subject='Abstract Reasoning' OR
    Subject='English' OR
    Subject='Mathematics' OR
    Subject='Science'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: gud one. but i need to pull up 10 abstract reasoning items from the table. gud suggestion anyway. thanks